# Float nav items to the right in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How do you push to the right nav items of a Bootstrap 4 navbar? I tried float-*-right but did not work.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse float-*-right">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I need to align the nav items to the right.

Comment: Some code would be great, so we can see the actual issue

Comment: You need 'pull-right' class: http://www.bootply.com/VljzqtNw5S (if such class exists in version 4).

Comment: Neither `float-right` or `pull-right` work because Bootstrap 4 now uses flexbox. [Now ml-auto is used to push nav items to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-item-to-the-right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 'float-xs-right' class to the ul

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav float-xs-right">
```

You can remove 'float-*-right' from the containing nav tag since it's not doing anything there

http://www.bootply.com/OnvcimHYD7

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2018**

`float-right` will no longer work because the Bootstrap 4 Navbar uses flexbox. The auto-margin class (ie:`ml-auto`) should be used instead.

See: 
[Bootstrap 4 align navbar items to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/bootstrap-4-align-navbar-items-to-the-right)